# Перевод текста в новостях

Tags: php, ajax, json

Необходимо реализовать функцию перевода текста как на фeйcбykе, то есть для того чтобы узнать перевод данной новости можно нажимать на кнопку перевести и перевод тут же выходит (заменяет стандартный текст на переведенный), вопрос в том есть ли готовые реализации / интеграции или можете предоставить готовую данную функцию (код, скрипт для реализации), не имеет значения переводчик. Благодарен за любой правильный или менее правильный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

для использования АПИ переводчика вам нужна серверная часть для запроса. 
поэтому необходимо искать либу под вашу платформу/язык. 
хотя имхо проще написать самому, поскольку ничего там сложного нет.
один запрос на апишку через curl и отдать ответ. 
вот тут пример.
https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/getting-started

на фронтенде запросить ajax запросом перевод и просто заменить текст.

Comment: ок, буду брать на заметку